# Set custom column headers in a DataGrid bound to List<double>

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to bind a `DataGrid` to an list of doubles. What I want try to do is set custom column headers (F1, F2, F3) for these doubles. The final result should look like this.

```
-------------------------------------------
|     F1      |      F2     |      F3     |
-------------------------------------------
|     12      |      15     |      25     |
-------------------------------------------
```

```asp
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CFactors}"  
          AutoGenerateColumns="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Values" Binding="{Binding}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>                
</DataGrid>
```

```c#
private List<double> cFactors = new List<double>
{
    12,
    15,
    25
};
public List<double> CFactors
{
    get { return cFactors; }
    set
    {
        cFactors = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CFactors");
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the question?

Comment: Thats not how it works. You have list and want to display it horizontally. Said, you want to pivot your  `CFactors`

Comment: If AutoGenerateColumns is true, the columns are generated automatically and the column header will be set based on the underlying model property. Here you have set the collection type as double. Can I know, how you have set the column header by customizing as you mentioned ?

Comment: @ElavarasanM Setting the custom column headers in what I want to do.

Comment: ok, you mean only the column headers are displayed and the records (12, 15, 25 ) are not showing right ?

Comment: @ElavarasanM None of them are displayed. I want the CFactors list to be displayed in the above format. Obviously since the list is only doubles, it doesn't have the header values. I want to enter the header values manually somehow. But I have no idea how to do it all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558714/binding-an-array-of-doubles-to-a-datagrid, Please look into this.

Comment: @ElavarasanM That's what I wanted to do but couldn't. Please see the code in my question.

Comment: `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">` just set the ItemsSource like this and set the DataContext as CFactors. Please let me know whether this is works.

Comment: @ElavarasanM No unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: I suspect the `cFactors' is not initialized, hence the CFactors having the empty list. Please try by setting value in CFactors itself instead of using private variable 'cFactors'.

Comment: @ElavarasanM I checked in the view model. It actually returns value.